# Can I chain "or" statements like this?

Tags: php

Given these variables:

```
$bar = false;
$baz = false;
$boo = "hi there";
$jelek = false;
```

When I chain `or` together like this:

```
$foo = $bar or
$foo = $baz or
$foo = $boo or
$foo = $jelek;

echo $foo;
```

It returns `hi there`! So, is this correct usage of `or`? Because if so, it's pretty sexy.

Comment: Sadly, `or` does not actually work how you'd want it to: http://ideone.com/vTlyP (specifically, it forces a cast to boolean).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you *can't* do in PHP what you could in, say, JavaScript:

```
var $foo = $bar || $baz || $boo;
```

What you can use, however, is [chained ternary operators](http://ideone.com/s8iqK):

```
$foo = $bar ? $bar : (
       $baz ? $baz : (
       $boo ? $boo : (
       NULL)));
```

It's not great, because of the repeated variable names, but it chains *okay*.

```
$foo = $a ? $a : (
       $b ? $b : (
       $c ? $c : (
       $d ? $d : (
       $e ? $e : (
       $f ? $f : (
       NULL))))));
```

---

Alternately, just [stuff them all inside a list and loop over it](http://ideone.com/DZEVA), taking the first truthy value found.

```
$foo = NULL;
foreach (array($bar, $baz, $boo) as $val) {
    if ($val) {
        $foo = $val;
        break;
    }
}
```

This option is, IMO, by far the most readable, maintainable, and easy to understand.

Comment: The latter, unaccountably, requires all of the extra parentheses that I edited in. It works without them in *every other language* that inherited C's operators, but PHP messed up the operator precedence on `?:`, making them work in an unintuitive and useless way. :(

Comment: The left-associativity of PHP's ternary operator means that this is *not a good idea*! You will get surprising results. Your linked example is a *perfect* demonstration, because it returns `$boo` instead of `$baz`!

Comment: The last suggestion is easy to understand, yes, but it means evaluating everything in the array.

Comment: @IsaacLubow I actually don't know PHP well enough to know if that's true. Is that the case because the variables are evaluated when `array()` is called? Otherwise, I'd think the `break` stops the evaluation as soon as a truthy value is found.

Comment: @MattBall In my actual code I'm comparing the return values of functions (either objects or `false`). It may be that a variable isn't evaluated when grouped into an array but I was assuming that a function would be. Now I'm curious...

Comment: @IsaacLubow ah, yes. If you're using functions, those will definitely be called as the array is constructed, like so: `array(bar(), baz(), boo())`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `or` in this way because `or` will just return a boolean.  You could do this with nested ternary operators, which would be kind of cool but I would hardly call it cleaner.  I don't think there is any better way to do it than the first method you listed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `or` the way you wanted. but you can do:

```
$foo = $bar ? $bar : (!$baz ? $boo : $baz);
```